# Django: in rawSQL get limit of rows and date.year

Tags: sql, database, django, web

I want to fetch the items with outDate in year 'year', and only fetch the top 'num' rows.

Here are my code

```
            year = form.cleaned_data['year']
            num = form.cleaned_data['limit']

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT br.callNumber_id, bk.title, COUNT(br.callNumber_id) as borrows FROM books_borrowing, books_book bk WHERE bk.id = br.callNumber_id br GROUP BY br.callNumber_id ORDER BY borrows DESC" )
            books = cursor.fetchall()
```

I tried to add LIMIT num and year(br.outDate) = year but I received error saying my syntax are not correct. I'm using mySQL with Django.

What should I do to implement my SQL?

Comment: you forgot a , between `books_borrowing br books_book bk`

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: you forgot a `,` - a comma

Comment: This wouldn't solve my problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query syntax doesn't look quite right.. You need to alias books_borrowing with br correctly.

Try the following:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT br.callNumber_id,
           bk.title,
           COUNT(br.callNumber_id) AS borrows
    FROM books_borrowing br,
         books_book bk
    WHERE bk.id = br.callNumber_id
    GROUP BY br.callNumber_id
    ORDER BY borrows DESC
    """)
```